# Select rows with greatest value

Tags: sql, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

I have a MS Access query called `qryA380` that uses multiple `INNER JOIN` to join a couple of tables.
Running the query will show the results like this:

```
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
| ID |  Aircraft | Route.ID | Passengers |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
| 23 |   A-380   |    1     |     556    |
|  2 |   A-380   |    2     |     652    |
| 54 |   A-380   |    2     |     489    |
| 16 |   A-380   |    1     |     598    |
| 39 |   A-380   |    1     |     627    |
| 45 |   A-380   |    3     |     392    |
| 74 |   A-380   |    3     |     726    |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
```

My plan is to select the smallest `Route.ID` (in this case it's 1) and the final result should be:

```
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
| ID |  Aircraft | MinRoute | Passengers |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
| 23 |   A-380   |    1     |     556    |
| 16 |   A-380   |    1     |     598    |
| 39 |   A-380   |    1     |     627    |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+
```

I thought this would be straight forward and simple. To save some time, I create a second query to do this work:

```
SELECT [qryA380].ID, [qryA380].Aircraft, MIN([qryA380].Route.ID) AS MinRoute, [qryA380].Passengers
FROM [qryA380]
GROUP BY [qryA380].ID, [qryA380].Aircraft, [qryA380].Passengers
```

But I kept getting a table identical with the table generated by `qryA380`. It has all the `Route.ID` on the results.

Comment: Just eyeballing, because the passenger total is unique, when you include it in your grouping, you are returning all the rows. You need to exclude the passenger totals from your grouping to get your desired results.

Comment: The passenger column is what I want to show. By excluding it from grouping I'll get an error saying "the query does not include the specified expression 'Passengers' as part of an aggregate function."

Answer (score 0):

The Passenger and ID column should be excluded since they have unique values. By using a Subquery, I'm now able to generate the desired results:

```
SELECT [qryA380].*
FROM (
  SELECT MIN([qryA380].Route.ID) AS MinRoute
  FROM [qryA380]
) tblMinRoute
INNER JOIN [qryA380]
ON [qryA380].Route.ID = tblMinRoute.MinRoute
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   SELECT [qryA380].*
    FROM [qryA380]
    WHERE [qryA380].Route.ID = (
            SELECT min(Route.ID)
            FROM [qryA380]
            )
```